# Formatting NgbDate

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I have a datepicker using NgbDate. I would like the format to spell out the month, hyphen, year. For example, August-2020. How can I format the following date this way?

```
effectiveDate = new NgbDate(date.year, date.month, date.day);
effectiveDate = effectiveDate.month.toString() + '-' +
                effectiveDate.year.toString();
```

Comment: It's about a time to choose the answer (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// the `effectiveDate` is of type `NgbDate`
effectiveDate = new NgbDate(date.year, date.month, date.day);
// you try to assign `string` to `NgbDate` which could work and it's very confusing
effectiveDate = effectiveDate.month.toString() + '-' +
                effectiveDate.year.toString();


// instead it's better to create a variable for string value + string interpolation will make it easy to read
const formattedDate = `${effectiveDate.month}-${effectiveDate.year}`;


// or you can convert `NgbDate` into `Date` in the controller
this.jsDate = new Date(effectiveDate.year, effectiveDate.month - 1, effectiveDate.day);
```

```html
// and use the `date` pipe in the component's HTML
jsDate | date: 'MM-yyyy'
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.